# browser url encoding different that java's URLEncoder.encode

Tags: url, decode, encode, space

I have a url like this:
product//excerpts?feature=picture+modes

when i access this url from browser, the backend receives the request as:
"product//excerpts?feature=picture+modes"

At the web server end, i am using + as a separator. so feature=picture+modes means there are 2 features: picture and modes

I have created and automated script(Java) which goes to the url and retrieves its content.
When i run this script, the backend receives the request as:
"product/B000NK6J6Q/excerpts/feature=picture%2Bmodes"

This is because inside my script(Java) i use URLEncoder.encode which converts + to %2B and send this encoded url to the server.

Why are the urlEncoders provided by Java and those present with browsers(FF/IE) different.
how do i make them same? How do i decode them? ('+' on URLDecoder.decode gives space)
Also, is using '+' as a separator according to conventions (and specifications?) ?

Prac

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing is actually correct. See [Percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_encoding) on Wikipedia. The `+` character is a reserved character and therefore needs to be encoded as `%2B`. Furthermore, historically browsers use a different form of percent encoding for forms that are submitted with the MIME type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` where spaces become `+` instead of `%20`.

If you want to use a `+` in the URL then your separator should be a space in the backend. If you want to use `+` in the backend, then you will have `%2B` in the URL.